# Cardview shadow not showing properly on api 18

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am using cardview like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/togglebuysell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">
```

The result on devices running api >21 is :
[image]
Which is `OK`
But on devices running api 18 the result is:

[image]
The shadow looks bizarre. any solution to fix this on all api versions?

Answer (score 0):

> CardView adds additional padding to draw shadows on platforms before Lollipop.

Try adding `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView#setusecompatpadding